# Customizing a DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to set a custom layout for my date picker.

This is my DialogFragment:

```
public class MyDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listener = (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Return custom dialog...
        DatePickerDialog dialog =  new DatePickerDialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), this, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)-18, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); //

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        listener.onDateSet(view, year, month, day);
    }
}
```

This is the custom layout I want to set to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:spinnersShown="true">

</DatePicker>
```

I don't know how to set it to it. How do you do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the problem right, so would you like to know how to set a custom layout to a dialog containing the `DatePicker`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using OnCreateView instead and referencing my picker and button in the layout and calling the listener method for onDateSet after assigning my activity as the implementation. Here is what it looks like:

```
public class AwesomeDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_picker, container);
        listener = (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity();
        Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.picker_button);
        final DatePicker picker = view.findViewById(R.id.awesome_date_picker);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onDateSet(picker, picker.getYear(), picker.getMonth(), picker.getDayOfMonth());
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```